How quickly does water accelerate over a spillway?
I'm designing an emergency spillway for a basin which has broad-crested weir that's 10' wide and 3:1 side slopes. From HydroCAD, I know that the flow rate over this weir is about 12.65 CFS. Using the weir equation, the depth for this flow was determined to be about 0.61' and the velocity was found to be about 1.75 ft/sec.
The broad-crested weir is generally flat, but then flows downhill at a 5:1 slope towards a lake. Using Flowmaster to complete a Manning's equation, I calculated that with an n-value of 0.40, the velocity in the channel increases to about 5.64 ft/sec.
This resulted in the need for some very large stabilizing riprap. However, I am not sure if the answer is correct for my situation. If I recall correctly, Manning's doesn't really consider the acceleration of water and presumably, if water was traveling through a spillway for 10' at a 5:1 slope it would be slower than if it were on the same slope for 100'.
Is this correct? If so, is there a standard criteria to adjust the results of a Manning's calculation to consider acceleration?

So, would it be gravity that causes the acceleration?

@SolarMike correct. I'd thought I might use Bernoulli's equation for an open channel flow, but due to water's ability to transition between subcritical and supercritical flow, I wasn't sure if the depth value would change between the first and second points never mind figuring out how to calculate the losses.

That 100' slows things down would suggest viscosity plays a factor, and the acceleration you may not be sufficiently considering in your mental model is the negative component.
